# How to run .py-file and stop at desired statement while developing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6

Hello my dearest stackoverflow community,

I want to run a .py file until a certain position. Certain IDEs might support the feature "run all above" but it seems like I am failing to use PyCharm properly, as I need the python console at all times to browse variables n stuff.

So - is there a way to stop the execution of the program in a proper manner? (edit: without shutting down the python console, such that further commands can be run to inspect / use obtained variables)

Obviously there are workarounds: throw exceptions, program the file into a while loop and break - but these cant be proper solutions, right?

edit:
A few answers are hinting already, that this could easily be solved while using debugging functions - however, using debugging functions might not always be possible as .py files could be executed remotely [without proper interface for debugging], loading a "standard" version, while a more "advanced / experimental" version could also run more chunks of code in that .py file.
(Yes, I am aware that this actually might be considered shitty development - as running functions and having proper parameters would also solve this, I guess.)

Please educate me, I didn't find the information I was looking for using google, as everything that was shown showed loop-relevant actions.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the debugger in pycharm. You can set breakpoints and the code execution will stop wherever you want it to stop. Once it is stopped you can see the values of all variables, can evaluate expression or start a python console which has access to all variables and run commands there.

You might wan't to read the short introduction to all features:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: thanks for the answer! u are right, i could use a debugger - however i am looking for a way that would actually be usable via remote terminal as well. - i will add this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a python debugger. In PyCharm you can just click on the line where you want the program to stop (on the left side, where the line numbers are). Then there should be a red circle on that line (a breakpoint) and then debug (run) the program with the green "Bug" icon instead of the green arrow. The debugger then stops at that point und you can investigate variables, change them on the fly or even execute some statements.

For more information, try the [tutorial from jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html#).

Edit after additional requirement of remote debugging:

You can also remote debug with a debugger, there are multiple ways to do this and I am not sure what your usecase exactly is. There is the possibility to run and debug your code with a remote debugger or integrate a debugger to normal running scripts on the remote server. This seems to fit your requirement?

This is the official link for PyCharm: [Remote Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#)

Comment: thanks for the answer! u are right, i could use a debugger - however i am looking for a way that would actually be usable via remote terminal as well. - i will add this to the question.

Comment: I extended my answer with the remote debugging possibility. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey, thanks for extending the answer, i just got the chance to look over it.
No, not really. I am really rather looking for a way to have a x.py file, which has a part above a certain point that stops the program, and also below. The point that should stop the program could be an error (no code will be run past that), but I would like to just make the console leave the file. Ideally things like exit() would work, but it pwns the console...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can cheat a little:

```py
a = "test"
b = "ing"

# quick debug
print(a)
print(b)
exit()  # the program will stop here

c = f"{a}{b}"  # this will show only when you remove exit()
```

This isn't the best way to debug of course, but it can save time.

Comment: exit() raises the following in pycharm: To exit the PyDev Console, terminate the console within IDE.

Comment: However, this is another approach to the workarounds i tried to present - one could also raise a specific type of Error or a self written variant of it, as well as looping the inside of .py

Comment: This approach is IDE independent. Try with `sys.exit(0)`. You will have to `import sys`. Otherwise, you simply raise an exception instead of exiting. There are many ways to debug, it depends how much effort you want to put into it.

Comment: breaking the .py with sys.exit(0) causes the py console to shut down, such that no further arguments can be run using the obtained variables by said .py-file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of not facing such problems like this, is nesting code into functions and call them properly in order to control what part of the code should actually be executed.

However, a solution for this might still be relevant, especially for applications in data science, as many solutions are presented in a single file (/jupyter notebooks) in order to present all steps taken to obtain achieved results.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file in debug mode and set a breakpoint to stop the execution and inspect the variables. There is a shortcut in pycharm ^D to run a file in debug mode.